# Having trouble opening an xml file for parsing from SD card

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sd-card

I have created a blank .xml file on the SD card, and now I'm trying to open it for parsing.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document newDoc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
```

When it reaches the parse() method I get the following logcat:

```
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:131)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:186)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData4.saveData(SaveData4.java:76)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData4.onCreate(SaveData4.java:40)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-11 12:07:20.676: E/Exception(18774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What for do you need to parse a blank file? The exception says that the file is not a proper XML file.

Comment: @Neeta: first validate your xml file using any xml Validator like [xmlvalidation](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)

Comment: @Egor I want to add more xml to the file. Maybe I need to write to the xml file after I've made a DOM that I want to append?

Comment: @Neeta, You probably should consider always trying to keep your XML valid, let it contain at least a root tag instead of leaving it absolutely blank.

Comment: @Egor How would I create a root tag after creating the file programmatically?

Comment: @Neeta, There's nothing special, just write it as a String to the file.

Comment: @Egor Thanks, if you put all your comments in a proper answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because a blank file isn't considered a valid XML file by the parser. To be able to create, change and parse XML files dynamically, you need to make sure that your file is always valid. To make it valid from the start you should consider putting in just a root tag, and then add the information inside it - this way you won't get into trouble parsing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml file and root tag.

Comment: First check isEmpty than  try to parse. Emty file can not be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The xml file could be invalid. Please validate the xml before initiating parse method call.
here's a link to learn how to read xml file from sd card. Hope this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/87d7305179d75985) helps you.